# Why I don't need to specify SMTP server in mail?

Tags: shell, terminal, email

I know you need to specify your email address, password, and SMTP server when sending emails using command line tools such as sendmail, sendEmail, etc. This is also true in other languages such as using the Python SMTP module, `smtplib`.

I'm wondering why I can just use the default `mail` command to send emails without specifying this information.

ex. If I run the following, it will go through.

```
ls | mail <email.address>
```

Comment: It contacts the server directly. For example, `mail JackeyOL@gmail.com` results in `connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4023:1006::1b]:25` in my `/var/log/maillog` (this is Centos).

Comment: This default can be configured, for example `set smtp=your.smtp.server` in the `.mailrc` file (from [a random tutorial I found](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-send-mails-to-an-external-user-with-mailx-on-linux).

Comment: Do you mean that the smtp server is auto-determined by the email address I put it in? ex. `mail jackeyol@gmail.com` will set the default smtp server to smtp.gmail.com and `mail jackey@yahoo.com` will set the default smtp server to smtp.yahoo.com?

Comment: That's how I understand it.

Comment: I think you are right about that. Do you know what's the windows powershell equivalent of `mail`? Trying to send messages without specifying the smtp server but just couldn't find a command that works.

Comment: Try Superuser.com for questions about Powershell. Unfortunately my experience with it can be summarized on a postage stamp.

Comment: Appreciate the direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mail` is a Mail User Agent (MUA). It is one of the tools responsible for providing an interface to the email subsystem to a user. For example you can use it to send and email and to read messages that have been delivered in the traditional way to your system. It is concerned with users, not with delivery. You can have many MUAs installed on a system

`sendmail`, `exim`, `postfix`, etc. are Mail Transport Agents (MTA). These tools don't care about user friendliness but are instead responsible for sending and receiving messages. Only one of these will be present on a system. It should be configured to know how to handle processing (antispam, DKIM, DMARC, etc.), transmission (for example, direct delivery, via a smarthost, etc.) and delivery (mailfile, maildir, separate program, etc.)

When you send a message with an MUA it hands it off to the MTA for delivery

Comment: Do you mean whenever I'm using `mail` (which is an MUA), the transportation part is still handled by MTA? But why I don't need to specify my username and password?

Comment: SMTP doesn't require a username/password. Email providers such as Gmail may require one to authenticate your client to them, so that they can correctly send email on your behalf. As an example, my mail server (MTA) here at home is `exim`. It requires a username/password from my mail client (MUA), Thunderbird, to prove the message comes from me. Once it has the message, though, it doesn't need or use a password to send the message on to my intended recipients

Comment: Trying to make sure I understand correctly, correct me if I'm wrong: although some mail servers require a username and password. It's not a strict requirement. MUAs like `mail` don't need such authentication, but only destination email addresses.